# Getting a specific results from the pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame named `ipl` which contains match history of teams. In the data frame there are three specific columns `'Team1'`,`WinningTeam`, `'Team2'`. I want to get the total matches played by say `CSK` and `MI` and who won how many matches. The way I have done this is

```
mivcsk_df = ipl[((ipl.Team1 == 'Mumbai Indians') & (ipl.Team2 == 'Chennai Super Kings')) | ((ipl.Team1 == 'Chennai Super Kings') & (ipl.Team2 == 'Mumbai Indians')) ]
mivcsk_df['WinningTeam'].value_counts()
```

I got the desired answer.

I also did

```
H2H=ipl.groupby(['Team1','Team2'])
H2H.get_group(('Mumbai Indians', 'Chennai Super Kings')).shape[0]
H2H=ipl.groupby(['Team2','Team1'])
H2H.get_group(('Mumbai Indians', 'Chennai Super Kings')).shape[0]
```

I got the desired answer here also. But is there a more neater way to do this, since I think this is a more ad-hoc solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) the teams that [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) the specified values ?

```
cols, vals = ["Team1", "Team2"], ["Mumbai Indians", "Chennai Super Kings"]

out = ipl.loc[ipl[cols].isin(vals).all(axis=1), "WinningTeam"].value_counts()
```

Comment: Okay. So this  .all function is finding all possible combinations where we see Mumbai Indians and Chennai Super Kings

Comment: In this context and when chained with `isin`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this in a more concise and efficient way using the groupby and value_counts functions in pandas. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

mivcsk_df = ipl[(ipl['Team1'].isin(['Mumbai Indians', 'Chennai Super Kings'])) & (ipl['Team2'].isin(['Mumbai Indians', 'Chennai Super Kings']))]
mivcsk_matches = mivcsk_df['WinningTeam'].value_counts()

print("Total matches played between CSK and MI:", len(mivcsk_df))
print("CSK vs MI Head-to-Head:")
print(mivcsk_matches)
```

It first filters the DataFrame to include only matches between CSK and MI. Then, it uses the value_counts function to count the occurrences of each winning team, providing a concise way to get the number of matches won by each team.